# cannibals and missionaries

Tags: prolog, river-crossing-puzzle

I am a newbie to prolog and started learning prolog.
I found the missionaries and cannibals puzzle interesting to solve in prolog. I have researched a lot of forums and found the link which I think is a very good solution. But some how I am not getting the actual result. The moves on the output seem to be wrong. I tried to trace the program, everything seems perfect during the assignment of the values but somehow the solution is wrong.

I need experts help to know where exactly is the logical error.

Source: http://www.enrico-franchi.org/2008/12/missionaries-cannibals-and-prolog.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments of the post, there was *no* logical error, just an ill chosen output format.